# Null Pointer Exception with Array of Buttons when setting OnClickListener with putExtra added to Intents

Tags: android, arrays, button, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I am trying to write an Android puzzle game with level choices in first Activity and actual puzzle in second Activity.  The first activity must provide information about the puzzle number selected to the second activity so that the second activity can load the appropriate information.  This has worked fine until I tried to clean my code up and put my Buttons into arrays:

For instance,

I previously had:

```
    puzzle0 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.puzzle0);
    puzzle1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.puzzle1);
    puzzle2 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.puzzle2);


    puzzle0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Puzzle.class);
            intent.putExtra("LevelNumber", "0");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });


    puzzle1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Puzzle.class);
            intent.putExtra("LevelNumber", "1");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    puzzle2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Puzzle.class);
            intent.putExtra("LevelNumber", "2");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
```

The above code worked great and allowed me to get the correct information in the second Puzzle Activity and load the appropriate puzzle.

As I have developed many more puzzles, it seems fitting to use a for loop and automate this a bit:

```
private void initializePuzzleButtons() {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPuzzles; i++)
    {
        Log.i("Trial","A" + i);
        int puzzleButtonID = getResources().getIdentifier("puzzle" + i, "button", this.getPackageName());
        Log.i("Trial","B" + i);
        puzzleButtons[i] = (Button) findViewById(puzzleButtonID);
        Log.i("Trial","C" + i);
        final int j = i;
        Log.i("Trial","D" + i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPuzzles; i++)
    {   
        final int j = i;
        puzzleButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Puzzle.class);
                Log.i("Trial","E" + j);
                intent.putExtra("LevelNumber", j + "");
                Log.i("Trial","F" + j);
                startActivityForResult(intent, j);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The Log commands in LogCat show that the NullPointerException is getting thrown in the second for loop.  That is, the LogCat shows A1, B1, C1...,A2, B2, C3,... all the way to D6 (NOTE: numberOfPuzzles = 7), then has the exception thrown.

My rationale for using the j variable is that a final variable is needed (can't use just i) because as Eclipse shows: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable j inside an inner class defined in a different method" if j is not final.

I thought the j variable was causing the issue, but I replaced each j with the literal 0 and still got the NullPointerException

That is,

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPuzzles; i++)
    {   
        final int j = i;
        puzzleButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Puzzle.class);
                Log.i("Trial","E" + 0);
                intent.putExtra("LevelNumber", 0 + "");
                Log.i("Trial","F" + 0);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

still causes a NullPointerException.  I may be missing something easy here, but I have been racking my brain for hours.  I looked at others in similar dilemmas, but all responses I have found do not use "New View.OnClickListener" as argument for setOnClickListener (they use "this") since they do not need to send extras to the sub-activity and can allow the Activity to implement OnClickListener.  This would not work in my case since the Activity could only generically implement OnClickListener, and I need a specific string to be associated with each Button (using the putExtra command).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you post Logcat error then its easy to find what actual exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
int puzzleButtonID = getResources().getIdentifier("puzzle" + i, "button", this.getPackageName());
```

By

```
int puzzleButtonID = getResources().getIdentifier("puzzle" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I was so caught up in the details that I missed the misuse of "button" vs. "id".  I would upvote your answer, but do not yet have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple buttons with similar functions. I suggest you implement the OnClickListener in the Activity rather than creating anonymous listener for each buttons.

To distinguish which button is clicked, there are two ways to do that.
1. When you initialize the buttons, you can set the button with a tag using `View.setTag()`   method.

1. Using the resID.

In your case, I suggest you to use method 1, because you need to pass the level to the intent when button clicked. When you initialize the buttons, you can just simply set the button tag with the level value.

Then your code should look like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    private void initializePuzzleButtons() {
        ...
        puzzleButtons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        puzzleButtons[i].setTag(i);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int level = (int)view.getTag(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will give this a shot, as it is much cleaner than my current use of anonymous listener.  Do you have any thoughts on efficiency of one method over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think should use as per [link](http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/)

int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I missed this completely, such a simple fix!  Much appreciated.